# XSD complexType sequence needs to allow empty string

Tags: xml, datetime, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

This is a JAXB / XSD related problem. A `complexType` is defined as

```
<xsd:complexType name="IndustryDateTimeType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:date"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Time" type="xsd:time"></xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The new requirement is that the date that is passed in XML could be an empty string, say,

```
<startdate></startdate>
```

where `startdate` is of type `IndustryDateTimeType`.

I figure I cannot have a union of a `complexType` and String - a simple type (allowing empty string). `xsd:choice` does not seem to be a good solution in this case. I have tried various combinations, but they are not working.

Also I cannot ask user to write an XML element like this

```
<startdate xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how much of this question is really about JAXB and wanting it to be a string, but `<xsd:sequence>` will take a `minOccurs` if you just want to allow the tag to be empty.

```
<xsd:complexType name="IndustryDateTimeType">
  <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:date"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Time" type="xsd:time"></xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

You'll probably end up with a `null` in your JAXB object instead of an empty string, but I think that might be the best option.